# Getting unlink(.png): No such file or directory when opening pdf with an image using dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am trying to view an pdf I generate using dompdf with laravel and php. When I generate the pdf it gives "unlink(.png): No such file or directory" error.

I made sure the link to the image is correct which it is. I tried to change the temp file location in dompdf/options.php.

I suspect it has something to do with a temporary folder which dompdf doesn't have access to. I tried editing the temp file which I gave full permission.

show.blade.php file

```
<?php $image_path = '/storage/signatures/'.$independent->signature; ?>
<img src="{{ public_path() . $image_path }}" style='width:150px;height:50px;'>
```

dompdf/options.php

```
$this->setTempDir("C:/Temp");
```

Controller

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.otp', compact('data'));
```

Full error Message

[image: Full error message]

I open the view and expect to view the pdf with the image displayed, but I receive the "unlink(.png): No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Don't you also get a file and line number where that error occurs? Please share the full error message.

Comment: yes I do. I will edit my post to display full error message

Comment: According to the error message, $tempfile_plain == ".png", which is probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: Not expecting that at all, not even sure where it gets the .png part because it is a .jpg file. If display my Image_path it is "C:\HostingSpaces\Laravel\public\storage\signatures\image.jpg", which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Me too i struggled for the same error for 3 days. Also when i tried tricks mentioned above, none of them worked too. But when i changed the image file to **.jpg** file(extension) everything worked well.

```
<img src="{{ public_path('img/logo.jpg') }}" >
```

- Laravel version: 5.8.38
- PHP version: 7.3
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf version: 0.8.6

Answer (score 0):

I will try everything I can, but finally -> We **cannot using transparent Image** (can set the background of the image to white or another color you want)

$dompdf=new Dompdf\Dompdf();

$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

**$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);**

Comment: Please share more details about how you resolved the problem. The given code does not contain anything related to that background image